# Range for Datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I want to make my `DatePicker` allow you to select a start and end date to create a range. Much like when you use dates on airline sites... It has you pick a start and an end in one popup of the `DatePicker`.

The only examples I see for ranges are 2x `DatePicker` and they use one as start and the other as end.

Has anyone done this or know what properties to enable to get it to behave this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar Control instead, it allows you select multiple dates hence giving you a range of dates. All you will have to do is to change it's style to make it look like a DatePicker Control.

Here is a link for Customizing the Calendar Control:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx

Another one:
http://classpattern.com/wpf-popup-calendar.html#.V700jU197IU